# Curiosity on react(?) or javascript syntax

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, syntax, jquery-chosen

While exploring through react documentation(https://reactjs.org/docs/integrating-with-other-libraries.html), I found this code snippet:

```
class Chosen extends React.Component {

   componentDidMount() {
      this.$el = $(this.el);
      this.$el.chosen();
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
      this.$el.chosen('destroy');
    }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <select className="Chosen-select" ref={el => this.el = el}>
          {this.props.children}
        </select>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

the syntax I don't undertand is below:

```
ref = {el => this.el = el}
```

what does the statement refer to ? I get it is identical to :

```
ref = { el => {
            return this.el = el
            }
       }
```

but what does it mean ? what is the flow in this code ?

Comment: http://es6-features.org/#ExpressionBodies

Comment: It just a normal function to assign `this.el` to `el`, no need to return that statement. And `this.el` is used to interact with DOM nodes. Read more [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`el => this.el = el` is sorthand for `function(el) { this.el = el }` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

`ref` keyword used for get element reference for future use like `focus` event. We have two way to use `ref`.

#### Way 1 (using ref string)

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
    focusInput() {
        this.refs.inputAge.focus();
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <input ref="inputAge" />
        )
    }
}
```

By this way, all ref goes into `this.refs`.

#### Way 2 (Using arrow function)

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
    focusInput() {
        this.inputAge.focus();
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <input ref={ref => this.inputAge = ref} />
        )
    }
}
```

By this way we can keep ref wherever we want as we control on that by function.

Comment: thanks for awesome examples, but what is that assigning syntax , 
this.$el = $(this.el) ?
I have never seen such property name as $el. Is there some kind of meaning in there ? or just a convention ?